# Workflow Engines for C#

Tags: c#, workflow

While looking for info about workflow engines for C# i found little to no info at all, and also almost no feedback or experiences related to the use of them.

I'm looking for a workflow engine to help us develop an application in order to deliver a software solution to a current hand-executed business process.

Googling around i found Stateless, but not much experiences about it.

WF looks well documented but some (if not all) answers in SO aren't very fond of it.

Also seems like almost all of the open-source solutions were abandoned, there's no future (or present) to workflow implementations in C#?

Can someone share experiences or recommend something (Ideally free)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into the FlowEngine part of NxBRE: http://nxbre.dossot.net .

There's a CodeProject article about NxBRE here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404367/Basic-Help-on-NxBRE-Rule-Engine

There's also a brief rundown of other engines at this blog post: http://www.kahneraja.com/net-business-rules-engine-players/

Answer (score 1):

The absolute best c# workflow project right now is a new one being written by Daniel Gerlag.  https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core

Comment: That's a pretty blanket statement.  Care to share what features make your choice the "best".

Comment: The pickings in this space are sparse.  Assume, for example, as I do that WF is a dead project.  What other C# open-source workflow engines are there?  There's ObjectFlow, which has no out-of-box persistence and which hasn't been touched for three years.  There's NxBRE, which is really just a rules engine and also hasn't been touched for years.  There are commercial products such as WorkflowEngine.Net and Skelta but these are expensive and have clunky interfaces.  And that's about it.

Comment: That doesn't explain why your solution is the best. What makes it the "best"?

Answer (score 0):

[Warewolf](https://github.com/warewolf-esb/warewolf) is a very simple workflow designer that supports writing tests with mocks and asserts and is the only one to support workflow merging.